# how to write output file same as input file in spring boot batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am facing one problem writing code. My code is working but one logic I am not able to implement.

I have n number of txt file in input directory and I want to write same data with same file in output directory (of course there is business logic in it, am able to implement).

**So could you please let me know how to achieve it or any reference article would be fine for me.**

I am able to write data in defined file as per now but requirement is something like

```
want to achieve:--

input dir:-                               o/p dir file
input1.txt--------------------------------input1.txt
input2.txt--------------------------------input2.txt
input3.txt--------------------------------input3.txt

as per now I have done:--
input dir:-                               o/p dir file
input1.txt--------------------------------
input2.txt--------------------------------output.txt (for all three i/p file)
input3.txt--------------------------------

update:---

FlateFileItemWriter<MyObject> writer = new FlateFileItemWriter<MyObject>();
writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource("output/outputData.txt");
writer.setAppendAllowed(true); ----this is appending all data and writing into outputData.txt file

I want if I am reading data from input1.txt I should be able to write data into input1.txt in output directory.
```

Comment: Please provide some code. What have you tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sure @SimonMartinelli